# GPUImageMovieWriter produces video with empty frames when using sound input and filters on video camera

Tags: ios, video-capture, gpuimage

I am using the impressive GPUImage framework for iOS in order to filter the incoming stream of the camera, and save it afterwards. When it is done, I want to close the containing view, and open another that has the playback option, for viewing the movie you just shot. Thing is, when I do nothing fancy, I can finish the recording, save the file to the temp file, and copy that to the camera roll synchronically. But when I use input sound and filters, the GPUImageMovieWriter seems to slow down too much, and produces empty frames to the beginning or ending of the video.

To set up the filters and stuff, and make the preview of the live filtered image I do this:

```
videoCamera=[[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:outputURL size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = YES;
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;

_filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:_filteredVideoView];

blendFilter = [[GPUImageNormalBlendFilter alloc]init];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithCGImage:[mc getImage]];
[sourcePicture processImage];

[blendFilter addTarget:_filteredVideoView];
[videoCamera blendFilter];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

where all variables like outputURL and mc are all properly set. To start the actual recording I call this:

```
[blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
[movieWriter startRecording];
```

To stop recording and save to the camera roll I have this code:

```
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
[movieWriter finishRecording];
[blendFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath, nil, NULL, NULL);
[self gotoNextView];
```

Probably the file starts recording before the frames are coming through, and/or the file is being copied to the camera roll while the temp file is still being written. How do I make sure everything gets on the file, and how do I get notified when it's done so I can move to the next view?

Answer (score 0):

```
        [self.movieWriter finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler:handler]
```

Putting your save video code into the completion handler block will wait until the video is done recording.